# I cannot compress huge files (~120GB) [bash]

Tags: bash, split, compression, bigdata, tar

I want to compress a huge folder (~80GB) but the when I get ~6GB the process stops.

This was my initial code:

```
tar czvf 210723_VH00461_53_AAAGV5KHV.tar.gz 210723_VH00461_53_AAAGV5KHV/
```

I tried, as an alternative, to split the object along the compression...

```
tar cvzf - 210723_VH00461_53_AAAGV5KHV/ | split --bytes=20000MB - 210723_VH00461_53_AAAGV5KHV.tar.gz.
```

... but the same "error" (although no error message appears) persists. Any alternative or solution, please?

EDIT

The problem was the [length of path names](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compress/issues/54#issuecomment-20391653). I tried to run the compression within the main folder (larger name) and according a list with the following code:

```
$ find . -type f -not -path "./*fastq*/*" > mytar.list
$ tar -czvf - -T mytar.list | pigz -0 -p 32 > ../myobject.tar.gz
```

However, it seems created `tar.gz` file has always problems like: `tar: Unexpected EOF in archive`

Comment: I cannot identify anything clearly wrong. It should work. I would try another approach: separate packing and compression (although it should not be necessary):  `tar cf - 210723_VH00461_53_AAAGV5KHV/ | gzip -c > 210723_VH00461_53_AAAGV5KHV.tar.gz`

Comment: What is the host OS? What about free disk space?

Comment: The OS is CentOS and I have enough space for storing, so I guess problem is different... but thanks for the reply.